# Macro buttons in excel and become distorted and unusable

Tags: excel, vba

I've been using the same series of macro buttons in excel workbook for several years. Recently, the buttons have become broken:  unclickable, greyed out, and the text name of the button is distorted.

[image]

i'm able to use the buttons if i am precise and click in the upmost left-hand corner of the button. But if i click anywhere else on the button i need to close and reopen the file.

Comment: Are these buttons on a spreadsheet or a userform? If they are on a spreadsheet, are they ActiveX or form control buttons? Do they have the same behavior on other machine(s)?

Comment: What is your question - are you asking why this happened, or do you want to know how to fix it?

Comment: I assume you have ActiveX buttons on a sheet? I had several issues with ActiveX controls (sizing and position changed, sometimes depending on the screen resolution). Instead of buttons, I usually use rectangle shapes and assign a Macro to them.  Format the shape with a shadow and play with the border, fill color and font property.

Comment: Or use lightweight buttons like [this](https://davetallett26.github.io/excelclock.html)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.